# how to get hamburger menu to close by clicking outside of it

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, click, hamburger-menu

I'm trying to get my hamburger menu to close by clicking outside of the menu.  Right now the only way to close the hamburger menu is by clicking the X icon.  I would still like the menu to be able to close by clicking the icon, but also have the option to close it by clicking outside of the menu.  Does anyone have any solutions?

jsfiddle - https://jsfiddle.net/1h3eoewa/

```js
    jQuery(document).ready(function() {
  jQuery(".submenu").slideUp("fast");
  jQuery(".menutoggle").click(function() {
    var id = jQuery(this).attr("id").replace("toggle", "submenu");
    jQuery("#" + id).slideToggle("fast");
  });

  jQuery("#hamburger-nav-icon").click(function() {
    jQuery(this).toggleClass("open");
    jQuery("body").css("overflow", "hidden");
    if (jQuery("#hamburger-menu-cover").css("opacity") == "0") {
      jQuery("#hamburger-menu-cover").css("opacity", "1");
      jQuery("#hamburger-menu-cover").fadeIn(300).css("display", "table");
      jQuery("body").css("overflow", "hidden");
    } else {
      jQuery("#hamburger-menu-cover").css("opacity", "0");
      jQuery("#hamburger-menu-cover").fadeOut(300).css("display", "none");
      jQuery("body").css("overflow", "visible");
    }
  });
});
```

```css
    /*--------------------------------------------------------------
## Hamburger Menu
--------------------------------------------------------------*/
#hamburger-menu-cover {
  z-index: 5;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.9);
  position: fixed;
  font-size: 1.5em;
  text-align: center;
  right: 0px;
  top: 0px;
  opacity: 0;
  display: none;
  overflow-y: scroll;
  -webkit-overflow-scrolling: touch;
  overflow: hidden;
}
.hamburger-menu {
  background: #fff;
  width: 432px;
  height: 100%;
  border-right: 1px solid #808080;
  position: fixed;
  top: 0px;
  overflow-y: scroll;
  -webkit-overflow-scrolling: touch; // mobile safari
}
.hamburger-menu-container {
  margin-left: 33px;
  margin-top: 100px;
  padding-right: 32px;
  padding-bottom: 40px;
  overflow-y: scroll;
  -webkit-overflow-scrolling: touch; // mobile safari
}
.hamburger-menu-links li {
  list-style: none;
  font-family: 'freightlight';
  font-size: 36px;
  display: block;
  line-height: 57px;
  font-style: italic;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  text-decoration: none;
  text-align: justify;
}
.hamburger-menu-links li a {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #000;
}
.hamburger-menu-links li a:hover {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #000;
}
.hamburger-menu-links li a:active {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #000;
}
.hamburger-menu-links li a:visited {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #000;
}
.hamburger-menu-links ul {
  border-bottom: 1px solid #808080;
  padding-bottom: 30px;
}
.submenu li {
  font-size: 16px;
  font-family: 'Raleway', sans-serif;
  line-height: 36px;
  font-weight: 600;
  letter-spacing: 2px;
  font-style: normal;
}
.hamburger-menu-social-links h3 {
  margin-left: 40px;
  padding-right: 32px;
  margin-top: 47px;
  padding-bottom: 0px;
  list-style: none;
  font-family: 'freightlight';
  font-size: 18px;
  display: block;
  font-style: italic;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  text-decoration: none;
  text-align: justify;
  letter-spacing: 0px;
}
.hamburger-menu-social-links {
  padding-right: 0px;
  letter-spacing: 12px;
}

#hamburger-nav-icon {
  z-index: 20;
  width: 50px;
  height: 35px;
  position: relative;
  margin: 35px 30px;
  -webkit-transform: rotate(0deg);
  -moz-transform: rotate(0deg);
  -o-transform: rotate(0deg);
  transform: rotate(0deg);
  -webkit-transition: .5s ease-in-out;
  -moz-transition: .5s ease-in-out;
  -o-transition: .5s ease-in-out;
  transition: .5s ease-in-out;
  cursor: pointer;
}

#hamburger-nav-icon span {
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  height: 5px;
  width: 40px;
  background: #000;
  opacity: 1;
  left: 0;
}

/* Icon 3 */

#hamburger-nav-icon span:nth-child(1) {
  top: 0px;
}

#hamburger-nav-icon span:nth-child(2), #hamburger-nav-icon span:nth-child(3) {
  top: 12px;
}

#hamburger-nav-icon span:nth-child(4) {
  top: 24px;
}

#hamburger-nav-icon.open span:nth-child(1) {
  top: 8px;
  width: 0%;
  left: 50%;
}

#hamburger-nav-icon.open span:nth-child(2) {
  -webkit-transform: rotate(45deg);
  -moz-transform: rotate(45deg);
  -o-transform: rotate(45deg);
  transform: rotate(45deg);
}

#hamburger-nav-icon.open span:nth-child(3) {
  -webkit-transform: rotate(-45deg);
  -moz-transform: rotate(-45deg);
  -o-transform: rotate(-45deg);
  transform: rotate(-45deg);
}

#hamburger-nav-icon.open span:nth-child(4) {
  top: 8px;
  width: 0%;
  left: 50%;
}
#toggle1, #toggle2, #toggle4, #toggle7, #toggle8 {
  font-size: 12px;
  padding-left: 40px;
  padding-top: 25px;
  display: inline;
  position: absolute;
  color: #B2B2B2;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.5.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="hamburger-nav-icon">
  <span></span>
  <span></span>
  <span></span>
  <span></span>
</div>
<div id="hamburger-menu-cover">
  <div class="hamburger-menu">
    <div class="hamburger-menu-container">
      <div class="hamburger-menu-links">
        <ul>
          <li><a href="#">Item 1<i class="fa fa-ellipsis-h menutoggle" id="toggle1" aria-hidden="true"></i></a></li>
          <div class="submenu" id="submenu1">
            <li><a href="#">Sub Item 1</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Sub Item 2</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Sub Item 3</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Sub Item 4</a></li>
          </div>
          <li><a href="#">Item 2<i class="fa fa-ellipsis-h menutoggle" id="toggle2" aria-hidden="true"></i></a></li>
          <div class="submenu" id="submenu2">
            <li><a href="#">Sub Item 1</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Sub Item 2</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Sub Item 3</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Sub Item 4</a></li>
          </div>
          <li><a href="#">Item 3</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Item 4<i class="fa fa-ellipsis-h menutoggle" id="toggle4" aria-hidden="true"></i></a></li>
          <div class="submenu" id="submenu4">
            <li><a href="#">Sub Item 2</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Sub Item 3</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Sub Item 4</a></li>
          </div>
          <li><a href="#">Item 5</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Item 6</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Item 7<i class="fa fa-ellipsis-h menutoggle" id="toggle7" aria-hidden="true"></i></a></li>
          <div class="submenu" id="submenu7">
            <li><a href="#">Sub Item 1</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Sub Item 2</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Sub Item 3</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Sub Item 4</a></li>
          </div>
          <li><a href="#">Item 8<i class="fa fa-ellipsis-h menutoggle" id="toggle8" aria-hidden="true"></i></a></li>
          <div class="submenu" id="submenu8">
            <li><a href="#">Sub Item 1</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Sub Item 2</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Sub Item 3</a></li>
          </div>
        </ul>
      </div>
      <div class="hamburger-menu-social-links">
        <h3>Social</h3>
        <a href="#" target="blank" title="twitter">
<img src="<?php echo get_template_directory_uri(); ?>/images/hamburger-twitter.png" border="0" onmouseover="this.src='<?php echo get_template_directory_uri(); ?>/images/hamburger-hover-twitter.png'" onmouseout="this.src='<?php echo get_template_directory_uri(); ?>/images/hamburger-twitter.png'" /></a>
        <a href="#" target="blank" title="Facebook"><img src="<?php echo get_template_directory_uri(); ?>/images/hamburger-facebook.png" border="0" onmouseover="this.src='<?php echo get_template_directory_uri(); ?>/images/hamburger-hover-facebook.png'" onmouseout="this.src='<?php echo get_template_directory_uri(); ?>/images/hamburger-facebook.png'" /></a>
        <a href="#" target="blank" title="Pinterest"><img src="<?php echo get_template_directory_uri(); ?>/images/hamburger-pinterest.png" border="0" onmouseover="this.src='<?php echo get_template_directory_uri(); ?>/images/hamburger-hover-pinterest.png'" onmouseout="this.src='<?php echo get_template_directory_uri(); ?>/images/hamburger-pinterest.png'" /></a>
        <a href="#" target="blank" title="Instagram">
<img src="<?php echo get_template_directory_uri(); ?>/images/hamburger-instagram.png" border="0" onmouseover="this.src='<?php echo get_template_directory_uri(); ?>/images/hamburger-hover-instagram.png'" onmouseout="this.src='<?php echo get_template_directory_uri(); ?>/images/hamburger-instagram.png'" />
</a>
        <a href="#" target="blank" title="Snapchat"><img src="<?php echo get_template_directory_uri(); ?>/images/hamburger-snapchat.png" border="0" onmouseover="this.src='<?php echo get_template_directory_uri(); ?>/images/hamburger-hover-snapchat.png'" onmouseout="this.src='<?php echo get_template_directory_uri(); ?>/images/hamburger-snapchat.png'" /></a>
        <a href="#" target="blank" title="Youtube"><img src="<?php echo get_template_directory_uri(); ?>/images/hamburger-youtube.png" border="0" onmouseover="this.src='<?php echo get_template_directory_uri(); ?>/images/hamburger-hover-youtube.png'" onmouseout="this.src='<?php echo get_template_directory_uri(); ?>/images/hamburger-youtube.png'" /></a>
        <a href="#" target="blank" title="Bloglovin"><img src="<?php echo get_template_directory_uri(); ?>/images/hamburger-bloglovin.png" border="0" onmouseover="this.src='<?php echo get_template_directory_uri(); ?>/images/hamburger-hover-bloglovin.png'" onmouseout="this.src='<?php echo get_template_directory_uri(); ?>/images/hamburger-bloglovin.png'" />
</a>
      </div>


    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Basically, add a click event on `body` itself, and just make sure what you don't want to trigger the close blocks click events with `e.stopPropagation()`.

```
jQuery('body').on('click', function() {
  // code to close hamburger
});

jQuery('.hamburger-menu').on('click', function (e) {
  e.stopPropagation();
  // other code
});
```

Just apply these when you open it, and remove them when you close it.

You could add it something like this:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
    jQuery(".submenu").slideUp("fast");
  jQuery(".menutoggle").click(function(){
    var id = jQuery(this).attr("id").replace("toggle","submenu");
    jQuery("#" + id).slideToggle("fast");    
  })


 const bodyClick = function () { jQuery('#hamburger-nav-icon').click() };

 jQuery('#hamburger-nav-icon').click(function() {
    jQuery(this).toggleClass('open');
      jQuery('body').css('overflow','hidden');  
    jQuery('.#hamburger-menu').click(function (e) { e.stopPropagation(); });
    if (jQuery('#hamburger-menu-cover').css('opacity') == '0') {
      jQuery('#hamburger-menu-cover').css('opacity', '1');
      jQuery('#hamburger-menu-cover').fadeIn(300).css('display', 'table'); 
        jQuery('body').css('overflow','hidden').on('click', bodyClick);
    } else {
      jQuery('#hamburger-menu-cover').css('opacity', '0');
      jQuery('#hamburger-menu-cover').fadeOut(300).css('display', 'none');
        jQuery('body').css('overflow','visible').off('click', bodyClick);
    }
  });
});
```

May not be perfect, but should give you an idea of what to do.

Comment: How would I add this to my js?  I tried adding it in, but it didn't work.

Comment: Check my updated answer. May not be perfect, but should give you a general idea. See the extra bits to your two `jQuery('body')` lines and the extra `jQuery('.#hamburger-menu')` line.

Comment: I really appreciate the help.  But now my hamburger menu will not open.  Is there any way you could look at it again, js is not really my strong point so I don't see where the problem is.

Answer (score 0):

Based on @samanime answer, you can also do something like this, which checks for each click on the current document and toggles your burger menu when the click's destination isn't the hamburger menu:

```
jQuery('document').click(function(e) {
    var elem = jQuery('.hamburger-menu');

    if(!elem.is(e.target)) {
        elem.toggle(); // this has to be the code to collapse the burger menu
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to make it close on a click anywhere in the document but the menu.

```
$(document).click(function(e) {
  if ($(this).parents('#hamburger-menu-cover')) {
    return;
  }
  // code to close the menu
});
```

Comment: I believe you are not using wordpress, so you should know how to edit your own js files. Just add this code and replace my comment with the code to close the menu.